# Rails has_many through save fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to save my model, but failed to save it.

```
 #starship.rb

 class Starship < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :crew_members,inverse_of: :starship
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :crew_members

    has_many :holodeck_programs,inverse_of: :starship
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :holodeck_programs
 end
```

---

```
 #crew_member.rb

 class CrewMember < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to  :starship
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :starship
   has_many :holodeck_programs,through: :starship
 end
```

---

```
 #holodeck_program.rb

 class HolodeckProgram < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :starship
   belongs_to :crew_member
 end
```

---

```
#controller

def create
  #Starship,CrewMember and HolodeckProgram are new via CrewMember.new
  @crew_member = CrewMember.new(crew_member_params)
  @crew_member.save
  .
  .
end
  .
  .
private
 def crew_member_params
  params.require(:crew_member).permit(:name,:division,:starship_id,
  starship_attributes: [:name,:id,
  holodeck_programs_attributes: [:title,:starship_id,:crew_member_id]])
 end
```

Because there is no crew_member_id in holodeck_programs_attributes, validation error happen.

I can not use inverse_of: :crew_member because of through in crew_member.rb

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create any number of crew_members, holodeck_programs while creating a starship.

But you are trying to create many starships, holodeck_programs for a single crew_members, look into

```
def crew_member_params
  params.require(:crew_member).permit(:name,:division,:starship_id,
  starship_attributes: [:name,:id,
  holodeck_programs_attributes: [:title,:starship_id,:crew_member_id]])
 end
```

So you need to change the create to,

```
def create
  @starship = Starship.new(star_ship_params)
  @starship.save
end
```

and crew_member_params to

```
def star_ship_params
  params.require(:star_ship).permit(<attributes of star_ship>, holodeck_programs_attributes: [<attributes of holodeck_programs>], crew_members_attributes: [<attributes of crew_members>])
end
```

And also make sure that you have done all changes in the view accordingly

Please look into: [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for more information regarding nested attributes and its usage.

Comment: I do not understand your answer ```@starship = Starship.new(star_ship_params)
  @crew_member.save``` there is no relation with @starship and @crew_member

Comment: Actually thats a mistake made by me. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is to save starship,  I want to save crew_member and starship and HolodeckProgram at same time. However, How I can get crew_member_id before saving?

Comment: @YangChandler as you are using accept_nested_attributes for crew_members and holodeck_programs in your starship model, this lets you to crew_member and starship and HolodeckProgram at same time. You need to have a look into http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. And why you need the crew_member_id.